Turning user input into an int variable and printing doesn't work - Integer cannot be resolved
I'm trying simple things in eclipse, previously used tmcbeans for the moocfi course.
I want to print the user input as a number, but I get two errors:

import java.lang.Integer cannot be resolved (l.2)
Integer cannot be resolved (l.9)

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Integer;
public class MyFirstProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        scan.nextLine();
        int x = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.print(x);
    }

}

Tried searching for answers, but they didn't work

why not use scan.nextInt() ?

It worked, thanks. In moocfi I only learned Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
